# IUPAC Name of Carbon Suboxide (C3O2)

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I have searched the internet looking for the IUPAC name for carbon suboxide ($\ce{C3O2}$). Its structure is as follows:

$$
\ce{O=C=C=C=O}
$$

I did find one name [here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Carbon-suboxide) (*PubChem*), but as far as I know, a $\ce{C=O}$ at the terminal position of a carbon chain is not termed as ketone, so I am not sure if **1,2-propadiene-1,3-dione** is the right name for the compound.

Comment: "Preferred IUPAC name
Propa-1,2-diene-1,3-dione"   [Wikipedia](  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_suboxide)

Comment: Can't help but wonder why did it get 5 upvotes. -on signifies carbonyl group in general, not necessarily ketone. In this case the functional group is rather enone - the compound is diketene.

Comment: I call into question that this compound should be banned according to the recommendations of organic compounds. Is just a more fancy carbon dioxide. Also the iupac tag was dedicated years ago.

Comment: And the initial part of the comment should have been: I call into question that this compound should be **named** according to the recommendations of organic compounds.